# Adding Data to a MySQL Database from an HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

HI all i've a basic Web Form for putting data into a mysql database, I created code to report if i was connected to my Database correctly and it was so on completion of the form i tested it and it seems to do what i expected but when i goto my database no data was actually entered? I've tried this locally and on a server with both doing the same thing.  Here is my two .php forms for you to look that i used on my local machine to test in MAMP just incase i have done something wrong:

virtualWalkLog.php

```
<form action="hazardsform.php" method="POST"  />
  <p>ROUTE: <input type="text" name="ROUTE" /></p>
  <p>ADDRESS: <input type="text" name="ADDRESS" /></p>
  <p>LATITUDE: <input type="text" name="LATITUDE" /></p>
  <p>LONGITUDE: <input type="text" name="LONGITUDE" /></p>
  <p>HAZARD: <input type="text" name="HAZARD" /></p>
  <p>RISK: <input type="text" name="RISK" /></p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

hazardsform.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'virtualWalkLog');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

     if (!$db_selected) {
     die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
     }

     $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
     $value = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
     $value = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
     $value = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
     $value = $_POST['HAZARD'];
     $value = $_POST['RISK'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO rmbhazards (ROUTE, ADDRESS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', 
     '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";

     mysql_close();
```

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going through your script quickly you need to call `mysql_query($sql)` after

`$sql = "INSERT INTO rmbhazards (ROUTE, ADDRESS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', 
     '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";`

`mysql_sql` query will actually execute the query.

Also as `$value` should be unique

```
 $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
 $value2 = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
 $value3 = $_POST['LATITUDE'];

 -----
```

**SUGGESTION**  Since you have just begin ..I will suggest you try mysql_* for just concepts
but use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` .. You shold also know about sql injection

Here are some tutorials to help you

http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 6):

you are not exectuing your `query`, this is why no data is inserted. Try to place after

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rmbhazards (ROUTE, ADDRESS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')";
```

this

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

also all values are in one variable `$value`, so you will end up with all the same result in your table so change to this to fit your query

```
 $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
 $value2 = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
 $value3 = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
 $value4 = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
 $value5 = $_POST['HAZARD'];
 $value6 = $_POST['RISK'];
```

I would also sugeest you to stop using  `mysql_` api since they are depecrated, please switch to [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Furthermore you are ready to `mysql injection`. there is a nice tutorial here which explain you everything about that -> [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out my mistakes, after reading your comments i managed to get this working thank you.

Comment: Until i have read up on mysql_* i am going to work with a form, the form isn't going to be public knowledge to people, just to one person but can sql injection still find my form? also my form is sending latitude and longitude coordinates to my DB, The latitude sends perfectly but the latitude that is a negative number i.e. -6.12345 shows up in my database as 0. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: @futhark Is it a get form or a post one?

Answer (score 3):

you are assigning values to only one variable `$value` here

```
 $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
 $value = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
 $value = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
 $value = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
 $value = $_POST['HAZARD'];
 $value = $_POST['RISK'];
```

should be

```
 $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
 $value2 = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
 $value3 = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
 $value4 = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
 $value5 = $_POST['HAZARD'];
 $value6 = $_POST['RISK'];
```

Also call `mysql_query($sql);` for running the query.

Answer (score 2):

You are capturing all the input fields value into one variable. You need to execute mysql_query for it to work. Change this :-

```
     $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
     $value = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
     $value = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
     $value = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
     $value = $_POST['HAZARD'];
     $value = $_POST['RISK'];
```

to:-

```
 $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
 $value2 = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
 $value3 = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
 $value4 = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
 $value5 = $_POST['HAZARD'];
 $value6 = $_POST['RISK'];
```

Once you have done that, you need to call mysql_query($sql) to execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

just rename:

```
$value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
$value2 = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
$value3 = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
$value4 = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
$value5 = $_POST['HAZARD'];
$value6 = $_POST['RISK'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You kep all the variables as the same name

```
 $value = $_POST['ROUTE'];
 $value = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
 $value = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
 $value = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
 $value = $_POST['HAZARD'];
 $value = $_POST['RISK'];
```

change them to unique id's (as you referenced in the sql statement)

```
 $value1 = $_POST['ROUTE'];
 $value2 = $_POST['ADDRESS'];
 $value3 = $_POST['LATITUDE'];
 $value4 = $_POST['LONGITUTE'];
 $value5 = $_POST['HAZARD'];
 $value6 = $_POST['RISK'];
```

and change your query statement to actually execute

```
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO rmbhazards (ROUTE, ADDRESS, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, HAZARD, RISK) VALUES ('$value', '$value2', 
 '$value3', '$value4', '$value5', '$value6')");
```