# Adding to MySQL from Materialize Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, materialize

Before anyone says this is a duplicate, I have checked and tried the solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129418/adding-data-to-a-mysql-database-from-an-html-form) previously asked question. My question is different, I believe, because I don't have a separate php file - it's coded with tags in my HTML (so everything is in the same document).

Here is my PHP (database info left empty):

```
<?php

session_start();
    $dbhost = '****';
    $dbuser = '****';
    $dbpass = '****';
    $dbname = '****';

$connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);


$email=$_POST['email'];

$query="INSERT INTO tableName(email)
VALUES('$email')";

mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Here is my Materialize/HTML form:

```
<form action="/thankyou.php" method="POST">
        <p class="input-header">Enter Your Email:</p>
        <input id="email" type="email" name= "email" class="validate" required>
        <br></br>
        <input class="waves-light btn indigo lighten-2" type="submit">
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>

</form>
```

Any ideas for why it's not working? I checked my MAMP phpmyadmin database and nothing is getting added. Please let me know if you have any suggestions! Thanks!

Comment: Make separate php file for your server side implementation (insert query)

Comment: are you sure you pasted all the php mysql code, because `mysqli_query` is missing?

Comment: Yes, that's all my code. Maybe I am a little lost because I don't know what mysqli_query is. @pravindot17

Comment: @NitinDhomse is there a perceived benefit to doing that? I'm still learning how MySql works properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will help you: As you haven't added `mysqli_query` and because of that it wasn't adding data. Also here I am checking whether the form is submitted as you mentioned it's a single file.

```
<?php
// check if form is submitted
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $dbhost = '****';
    $dbuser = '****';
    $dbpass = '****';
    $dbname = '****';

    $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    // this line prevents sql injection
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);

    $query="INSERT INTO tableName(email) VALUES('$email')";
    // this statement runs your query and actually adds data to mysql
    if (mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($connection);
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hmm. I tested it and it still did not work. Any ideas why not?

Comment: what error you are getting? can you please update here

Comment: I'm not getting an error - I'm getting absolutely nothing. My database is empty and nothing echoes.

Comment: what happens when you submit the form? check what you are getting in `var_dump($_POST);` on top of page.

Comment: That's not even coming up. :( I'm using MyPHPAdmin if that helps.

Comment: if your form and php code is on same page then keep action of your form element to blank i.e `action=""`

Comment: Well, my action goes to another page that I need. Is that an issue?

Comment: yes of course, that was an issue as you have already said all your code is in one file